# C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: invalid reference format

Tags: docker

$ winpty docker run -it --name teamcity-server-instance \ -v C:\teamcityJet\data:\data\teamcity_server/datadir \ -v teamcityJet\logs:\opt\teamcity\logs \ -p 811er8111 \ jetbrains\teamcity-server

I use the docker toolbox , when i enter this command, i get this error message"C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox/docker.exe: invalid reference format.", somebody can help me what the reason is or what i have to change